# If two sample means are not significantly different, can we infer that the population means are equal?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, population, mean

Assume we compare two sample means from an experiment (Control and Treatment) using an appropriate statistic test.

According to the test, differences are not significant. H0 cannot be rejected.

Based on this test result, can we infer that the two population means are not different, i.e. that the treatment does not have an effect "in real life"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Counterquestion: Assume myself and Dirk Nowitzki (who has enjoyed the "treatment" of decades of basketball training, as well as talent) each throw three free throws, and we both happen to succeed twice. So there is zero difference between the sample means, which hence cannot be significant. Would you be willing to infer that I am no worse than Dirkules, i.e. that the treatment had no effect?

Comment: So, what you mean is that even if we can be reasonably sure (by conducting a a priori power analysis) that our sample size is indeed big enough, but findings still suggest the difference is insignificant, we cannot infer that population means are different? We would need a significant difference that is equal to 0 to be able to infer this?

Comment: My example was evidently geared to alerting you to the role of sample size - with small samples, power of the test is low. In general, as you point out, tests make mistakes, include type-II errors. Moreovery, there are many threads on this site which discuss how to properly interpret outcomes of a statistical test (e.g., read up on popular threads related to p-values).

Comment: My question did not concern problematic sample size, therefore my second comment. It is also not aimed at type II errors. I basically ask whether "not being able to reject the null hypothesis of equal means with two independent random samples" allows to infer "equality of population means". E.g. in regression, does a non significant coefficient allow me to conclude the effect it discribes is non-existent, or would I need a coefficient that is very close to 0 but significant? If your first comment answers this, I am not seeing it and I am sorry.

Comment: Well, your question *is* related to type II errors: because tests may fail to reject false null hypotheses, we cannot infer from a nonrejection that the null is true.

Comment: So, inferring that population means are equal because we fail to reject the null hypothesis that sample means are equal would leave us being wrong about this inference with a probability equal to the rate of the Type II error, which is a function of statistical power?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45416/discussion-between-dirk-and-christoph-hanck).

Comment: "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence!"

    -- Carl Sagan, Astronomer